# Stanza, but in a strange point

Tags: reledmac, verse

I am currently doing a comparative edition of a text that is based also on an older one. For this reason, I have a problem with the lining of the stanza numbering, whose presence is pivotal to the apparatus criticus.

I have to obtain the following typeset:

[image]

and at the same time, if I add a \edtext{}, for example, on consectetur and eiusmod, in the apparatus a 1.2 for the first and a 2.1 for the latter should appear.

Is there a way to obtain it?

Here you find the tex:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Specimen.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\greekfont{IFAO-Grec Unicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,german}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
        \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}
        \setkeys{german}{babelshorthands=true}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 
\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\numberstanzatrue
\setcounter{stanza}{0}
\stanza
\textgreek{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}&
\textgreek{consectetur adipiscing elit}\& 
\stanza 
\textgreek{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}&
\textgreek{ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}\& 

\numberstanzafalse
\endnumbering    



\end{document}
```

Comment: you should look on line number annotation mechanism, I guess (I am tired, so no time now for more explanation)